# Get data from Object with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I cant' access data from this Object "snapshots" and I don't know why :

```
[
{"action":"Afficher les détails ","cat":"Produits 1","image":"https://www.google.fr","lien":"https://www.google.fr","nom_intent":"1","reponse":"réponse 1","scat":"scat1"},
{"action":"Afficher les détails ","cat":"Produits 2","image":"https://www.google.fr","lien":"https://www.google.fr","nom_intent":"2","reponse":"réponse 2","scat":"scat2"},
{"action":"Afficher les détails ","cat":"Produits 3","image":"https://www.google.fr","lien":"https://www.google.fr","nom_intent":"3","reponse":"réponse 3","scat":"scat3"}
]
```

I get this object with this code :

```
function getFirebaseData(endpoint){
      return 
      firebase.database().ref('intent/'+endpoint).once("value", 
      function(snapshot){
            return snapshot.val();
      });
    }

Promise.all([
  getFirebaseData(entities.intent[0].value), 
  getFirebaseData(entities.intent[1].value), 
  getFirebaseData(entities.intent[2].value)
]).then(function(snapshots) {

});
```

and tried to access like this :

```
var action0 = snapshots[0].action;
```

but `action0` is `undefined`

Comment: Use `.done` in place of `.then`

Comment: @DavidR TypeError: Promise.all(...).done is not a function

Comment: `typeof snapshots` ? If it's a string you will need to `JSON.parse` it.

Comment: @GabrielBleu it's a beautiful object so I don't need to parse it but thanks !

Comment: `typeof snapshots[0]` ?

Comment: @GabrielBleu Object too !

Comment: `var action0` is defined inside `.then` right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157556/discussion-between-pablo-delanoche-and-gabriel-bleu).

Comment: Ensure the response is a JSON object before trying to access it

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick to get this thing done ! 
I delcared an array : `var firebaseData = [];`
 then I pushed in it all my values :

```
function getFirebaseData(endpoint){
          return firebase.database().ref('intent/'+endpoint).once("value", function(snapshot){
                firebaseData.push(snapshot.val());
          });
        }
```

And when the Promises are done, I access to this like that :

```
Promise.all([
    getFirebaseData(entities.intent[0].value), 
    getFirebaseData(entities.intent[1].value), 
    getFirebaseData(entities.intent[2].value)])
.then(function(snapshots) {
         var zero = firebaseData[0];
         var first = firebaseData[1];
});
```

Comment: Ho getFirebaseData was not returning a promise. You could change it to return a promise then your first solution should work.
`return new Promise(resolve => firebase.database().[...] { resolve(snapshot.val()) }));`

Comment: It's native, you just have to use `.once('value').then` instead of `.once('value', function` [see](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html)